# Why is the central fringe in Fabry-Perot inteferometer dark?

Tags: optics, interferometry

We know that when the beams have phase shift due to reflection, the central fringe would be dark. But in the Fabry-Perot interferometer, except the first beam, each beam reflects 2 times (external reflection), so they must have $2\pi$ phase difference. So why is the central fringe in Fabry-Perot inteferometer dark?

Comment: One can change the dark and bright fringes by changing the distance between the mirrors.